# How can I sum a range of numbers in Rust?

Tags: rust

I want to write a function to sum the numbers from zero to n. (Ideally, this would be generic over all numbers, but I will settle for `i32`).

```
mod squares {

    pub fn sum_from_zero( n: i32) -> i32 {
        [0 .. n].fold(0, |a, b| a + b)
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_sum_from_zero() {
    assert_eq!(15, squares::sum_from_zero(5));
}
```

I get the following compiler error:

```
src/lib.rs:5:18: 5:22 error: no method named `fold` found for type `[std::ops::Range<i32>; 1]` in the current scope
src/lib.rs:5         [0 .. n].fold(0, |a, b| a + b)
                              ^~~~
src/lib.rs:5:18: 5:22 note: the method `fold` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied: `[std::ops::Range<i32>; 1] : std::iter::Iterator`, `[std::ops::Range<i32>] : std::iter::Iterator`
```

I've also tried this with `sum()`:

```
mod squares {

    pub fn sum_from_zero( n: i32) -> i32 {
        [0 .. n].sum()
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_sum_from_zero() {
    assert_eq!(15, squares::sum_from_zero(5));
}
```

And got the following compiler error:

```
src/lib.rs:5:18: 5:21 error: no method named `sum` found for type `[std::ops::Range<i32>; 1]` in the current scope
src/lib.rs:5         [0 .. n].sum()
                              ^~~
src/lib.rs:5:18: 5:21 note: the method `sum` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied: `[std::ops::Range<i32>; 1] : std::iter::Iterator`, `[std::ops::Range<i32>] : std::iter::Iterator`
src/lib.rs:5:18: 5:21 error: no method named `sum` found for type `[std::ops::Range<i32>; 1]` in the current scope
src/lib.rs:5         [0 .. n].sum()
                              ^~~
src/lib.rs:5:18: 5:21 note: the method `sum` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied: `[std::ops::Range<i32>; 1] : std::iter::Iterator`, `[std::ops::Range<i32>] : std::iter::Iterator`
```

Do I have to declare explicit bounds/traits?

Comment: You're creating a single-element array of `Range<i32>` types (aka `[std::ops::Range<i32>; 1]`). You probably just mean `(0 .. n)`, which just changes operator precedence so that you're not invoking `sum()` on `n`. ([Playground Example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b27932d99482f3ddd62697b62f1fe28c&version=stable&backtrace=0))

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating an array of ranges (square brackets) but you just wanted the range (on which fold is defined).

Another thing is that range syntax (`..`) is only inclusive of the lower bound. It's exclusive of the upper bound so you have to iterate up to `n+1` to get the desired result.

```
mod squares {

    pub fn sum_from_zero( n: i32) -> i32 {
        (0 .. n+1).fold(0, |a, b| a + b)
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_sum_from_zero() {
    assert_eq!(15, squares::sum_from_zero(5));
}
```

Comment: As of Rust 1.11, the `Iterator` trait has a `sum` method and ranges are iterators, so no need to `fold`. Also, no mention of n×(n+1)/2?

Comment: @mcarton: Let's presume that he is interested in learning how to iterate and not in the closed form :)

Comment: Thanks arjan, mcarton, and matthieu-m. Yes, I like the Guass-ian shortcut, and yes, I'm really just trying to play with iterators, filters, and other FP things in Rust. 

Too much context switching between Rust and Haskell, I had confused the syntax for Range literals.

Comment: FWIW, on current stable Rust (release 1.9.0) I cannot use `sum` (https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27739).

Comment: @JonWolski Current stable is 1.12.1

Comment: Thanks, @Arjan. It turns out, I have my path misconfigured. `rustup` installed `1.12.1`, but I was still using a `1.9.0` from homebrew.

Comment: now rust can use `0..=n` and `0..(n+1)` two ways.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Iterator** trait, which includes the **sum** method, to sum a range of numbers. Here's an example implementation:

```rust
mod squares {

    pub fn sum_from_zero(n: i32) -> i32 {
        (0..=n).into_iter().sum()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Other people have given valid answers, but I assume the following is the simplest way to do it.

```rust
fn summation(n: i32) -> i32 {
    (0..=n).sum()
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::summation;

    #[test]
    fn basic_tests() {
        assert_eq!(summation(1), 1);
        assert_eq!(summation(8), 36);
        assert_eq!(summation(22), 253);
        assert_eq!(summation(100), 5050);
        assert_eq!(summation(213), 22791);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's true, and it's what I had initially tried, except that I had expressed my range in Haskell syntax `[0 .. n]` instead of Rust `(0 .. n)`. I resorted to fold, when the compiler told me `sum` was not implemented for my type. (In retrospect, of course it wasn't; I was trying to sum an array of ranges)